# Checking folder for discord.py requirements

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

My startup command I have for my discord.py bot installs requirements from a requirements.txt file and puts them into the specified folder (the requirements folder) but the issue I'm having is that the bot doesn't look into that folder for dependencies and just looks at the root folder instead

Is there a way I could make the bot look at a specific folder for dependencies instead of the root one? Because if I were to use the root folder, it'd make it look messy and harder to navigate

Here is the command I use:

```
pip install -U --target /home/container/requirements -r requirements.txt; fi; /usr/local/bin/python /home/container/bot.py
```

Comment: This was pterodactyl being dumb, I got this fixed a week or so after asking the question

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, You need to use a virtual environment.
You can do that with may ways `venv` `poetry` `pipenv`.

I recommend you use [pipenv](https://pipenv-fork.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) all you have to do is install your requirements.txt to the environment and then run your code inside of it.

`pipenv install -r requirements.txt`

Comment: No, I don't think that's what I need, I can already run the bot and install requirements, I just want to know if there's any way, on startup, that the bot will look in the requirements directory instead of the root directory the bot.py file is in and see the requirements and use them